# Online Neustadtl Sonneborn–Berger score?

Tags: programming, statistics, tie-breaks

Where can I find a site that calculates [Neustadtl Sonneborn–Berger score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonneborn%E2%80%93Berger_score#Neustadtl_Sonneborn%E2%80%93Berger_score) (or Sonneborn–Berger score or whatever) given a cross-table? Closest I found is [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/tournament-cross-table-with-sonneborn-berger-score/python).

Eg Given the cross-table (implied from these results by rounds) from [St Louis Chess Club's 2021 Chess 9LX tournament](https://www.uschesschamps.com/2021-champions-showdown-chess-9lx/pairings-regulations):

[image]

I calculated the ff: (And you can also see SB in the players' links in the 2nd column.)

[image]

Based on Neustadtl Sonneborn–Berger score, [Wesley So is 4th place behind Sam Shankland](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41615/what-exactly-does-sam-shankland-mean-by-talented-players-vs-hard-working-players) & MVL even though they are tied for 2nd place.

Comment: Tata Steel [publishes this](https://tatasteelchess.com/standings-masters/) with the crosstable.  I acknowledge you are looking for a website that returns SB given a crosstable.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan ok...... and then what? how do i plug in my cross table

Comment: @BCLC what is your input?

Comment: @ferdy a crosstable in google sheets? Well I mean it's pretty easy to do this. I just don't wanna reinvent the wheel. But I'm hoping I can go to some webpage instead of having to download some software hehe

Comment: Just in case you have not known this, I have a command line program called [pgnhelper](https://pypi.org/project/pgnhelper/) that can take pgn and output, txt, csv and html. There is SB in the generated table.

Comment: @ferdy ah thanks. like input a pgn of several games in a completed tournament  and then you get SB?

Comment: Yes, even if the tournament is not yet complete.

Comment: @ferdy feel free to post your command line programme as an answer. doesn't look like there's a webpage for direct input. sigh.

Answer (score 1):

[pgnhelper](https://pypi.org/project/pgnhelper/) is a command line tool to generate a round-robin table along with some tie-break systems one of which is the SB. It can take a pgn file and output to html, csv and txt formats.

#### Setup

0. Install python 3.7 or later like 3.10
1. Open command prompt or powershell if you are in windows.
2. Install the package with the command:

```
pip install pgnhelper -U
```

##### Example

```
PS F:\Github\position-trainer\pgn> ls


    Directory: F:\Github\position-trainer\pgn


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2023-02-12     23:50         536764 airthingsmastpl23.pgn
-a----        2022-09-21     02:52        1516345 cheurind22.pgn
-a----        2022-09-21     02:50         114370 ftxcrpyto22.pgn
-a----        2022-08-14     17:01        3859792 olym22.pgn
-a----        2022-09-08     10:37          87717 stlbli22.pgn
-a----        2022-09-08     20:26           1719 stlbli22_2games.pgn
-a----        2022-09-08     20:05           3602 stlbli22_4games.pgn
-a----        2023-02-12     23:59          85511 tatamast23.pgn
-a----        2023-02-13     00:04         775054 wbliw22.pgn
-a----        2023-02-15     16:32        2575075 world_blitz_women_2022.json


PS F:\Github\position-trainer\pgn> python --version
Python 3.10.6
PS F:\Github\position-trainer\pgn> pip install pgnhelper -U

PS F:\Github\position-trainer\pgn> pgnhelper roundrobin --inpgnfn tatamast23.pgn --output tatamast23.html
```

#### output

tatamast23.html

[image]

#### Standing

You can also use standing directive to output the standings.

```
pgnhelper standing --inpgnfn tatamast23.pgn --output stand_tatamast23.txt
```

#### Output

```
 Rank                   Name  Rating   RChg  Games  Score  Score%  DE  Wins    SB  Koya
    1            Giri, Anish    2764  15.41     13    8.5   65.38 0.0     0  0.00   0.0
    2 Abdusattorov, Nodirbek    2713  20.49     13    8.0   61.54 1.0     4 51.25   5.0
    3        Carlsen, Magnus    2859  -7.56     13    8.0   61.54 0.0     5 48.00   4.0
    4             So, Wesley    2760   6.20     13    7.5   57.69 0.0     0  0.00   0.0
    5    Maghsoodloo, Parham    2719   9.31     13    7.0   53.85 0.5     4 42.50   3.0
    6       Caruana, Fabiano    2766   0.02     13    7.0   53.85 0.5     2 43.75   3.0
    7       Rapport, Richard    2740   0.16     13    6.5   50.00 0.5     3 37.75   2.0
    8         Aronian, Levon    2735   1.15     13    6.5   50.00 0.5     1 41.25   3.0
    9      Praggnanandhaa, R    2684   6.15     13    6.0   46.15 1.0     2 38.75   3.0
   10    Van Foreest, Jorden    2681   6.73     13    6.0   46.15 0.0     2 38.50   3.5
   11            Ding, Liren    2811 -23.71     13    5.5   42.31 1.0     1 35.00   3.0
   12              Gukesh, D    2725  -6.88     13    5.5   42.31 0.0     2 35.00   3.0
   13        Keymer, Vincent    2696  -6.18     13    5.0   38.46 0.0     0  0.00   0.0
   14        Erigaisi, Arjun    2722 -21.28     13    4.0   30.77 0.0     0  0.00   0.0
```

[Tie-break](https://pgnhelper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-pgnhelper.roundrobin) is described in the [documentation](https://pgnhelper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). The [source code](https://github.com/fsmosca/pgnhelper) is in github.

#### Chess 9LX

pgn source is from [weekinchess](https://theweekinchess.com/chessnews/events/champions-showdown-9lx-2021).

```
pgnhelper roundrobin --inpgnfn champshow9lx21.pgn --output 9LX.html
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent.